# Get context from a String which resembles Package.activity

Tags: android

I have an Android app with 3 activities. MainActivity,SecondActivity,ThirdActivity. I have an external Java class in another package of my app. In that Java class, I have a loop for checking the execution of these Activities. In this loop I have a String that gives the current execution activity along with package something like mypackage.activity.

For the first execution, I am getting String as com.example.MyActivity. The next execution gives the value as com.example.SecondActivity.  So each time I have this string, I need to get the context of that particular package and activity from this external Java class. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think you can make every activity to send its context to the external class and then retrieve it when ever you need it

Comment: But i dont want to touch the 3 activities. Whatever modification i do i want to do in this external java class.

Comment: Ok can I ask how does the external class know the package name of the activity

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow need to get the context, you can create a BaseActivity, extent your three activities from that BaseActivity and then in your BaseActivity write a method to just return itself as a context. Or if you need the context somewhere just go ahead and pass it!